# Javascript numerals only. How to have a 2 fixed decimals?

Tags: javascript

I have this function to write numerals only and permit 1 comma only (dots automatically convert to commas).

I need the number to be 2 decimal and not more. If the person writes `12,345` the 5 automatically has to go off.

This is the function:

```
function inputControl(input){ 

    if($('.max-value-overflow').is(':visible')){
      $('.max-value-overflow').hide();
    }

    var value = input.val();
    var values = value.split("");
    var update = "";
    var transition = "";

        var expression=/(^\d+$)|(^\d+\.\d+$)|[,\.]/;
        var finalExpression=/^([0-9][0-9]*[,\.]?\d{0,3})$/;

    for(id in values)
    {           
        if (expression.test(values[id])==true && values[id]!='')
        {
            transition+=''+values[id].replace('.',',');
            if(finalExpression.test(transition)==true)
            {
                update+=''+values[id].replace('.',',');
            }
        }
    }
    input.val(update);
}
```

I tried changing the last line to this:

```
input.val((update).toFixed(2));
```

But didn't work. I keep on getting the number in full (12,345) instead of taking away the last number.

Comment: *"But didn't work"* yey! :D What exactly? what's the error?

Comment: In the number you have provided (12,345) there is no decimal point. If 5 is removed (as you suggested), then the value will change totally. Is it okay?

Comment: Yes @VimalanJayaGanesh It has to become a 2 decimal (but with comma and not dot).

Comment: So, what is the expectation for this number: 12,345,334 (which has more than one comma)? Will this situation occur in your case?

Comment: As you can see from the regex there is no way of 2 commas (only one stays). I'm using the comma instead of dot.

Answer (score 1):

It's because your input is a String and `.toFixed()` only works on Numbers.
You should parse it with `parseInt()` before you use `.replace('.',',')`, otherwise you will get a String again, since `replace()` returns a String

Answer (score 0):

`update` in your case is a string. Try coercing to a number like

```
input.val((+update).toFixed(2));
```

or with `parseInt` like

```
input.val(parseInt(update).toFixed(2));
```

Also, note, `toFixed` will only work for values with decimals, not commas, so

```
(+'12,345').toFixed(2) => 'NaN'
(+'12.345').toFixed(2) => '12.35'
```

Comment: @Mr.Web, help me help you. What does *not working* mean? Are there error messages? Is the `toFixed` part not working?

Comment: Is not working means it does not do what it is supposed to. It keeps on giving the 3 numbers at the end and not 2. But see my answer...!

Answer (score 0):

Got it. It was a mistake in the regexp:

```
var finalExpression=/^([0-9][0-9]*[,\.]?\d{0,3})$/;
```

Had to be:

```
var finalExpression=/^([0-9][0-9]*[,\.]?\d{0,2})$/;
```

(Notice the number 2 near the end instead of 3.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution:

Solution applied:

- Split the comma separated number to array
- Verify and make the last index value to 2 digit
- Store the value back to array
- Convert the array back to comma separated number

```js
function ConvertTo2Decimal(num)
{
  var numArr = num.split(',');

  if (numArr.length > 1)
  {
    var lastIndexValue = numArr[numArr.length - 1];
    
    if (lastIndexValue.length > 2)
      {
        lastIndexValue = lastIndexValue.substring(0, 2);
        
        numArr[numArr.length - 1] = lastIndexValue;//set the new value
        
        num = numArr.join(",");
      } 
  }
  
  return num;
}


document.write(ConvertTo2Decimal("12,345"));
document.write("<br/>");
document.write(ConvertTo2Decimal("390,512,3455"));
```